# A good lab demonstration of this particular optical transform pair?

Tags: spectroscopy, crystallography, light

At about 1:11 the video linked below shows what think is the optical Fourier transform of a sine wave as approximated by a saw blade.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jzmqeRp_tmk

The set-up *appears* to be a high-quality 4F system with a green laser, two lenses, and a display screen--a good apparatus for demonstrating Fresnel diffraction.* This video is the closest I have found to a simple visual demonstration of the $\sin \leftrightarrow F(sin)$ Fourier transform pair (but it isn't exactly that).

My question is whether it is possible to demonstrate the $\sin\leftrightarrow F(\sin)$ pair optically in the lab.

*Fresnel diffraction here just means the aperture is not small.

Comment: For the close votes: I edited the question and found an authoritative answer to this question which is not opinion-based.

Comment: Back in the day when X-ray diffraction still was recorded on film, the symmetry relationship was demonstrated with $\pu{35 mm}$ slides with such patterns. Lisensky *et al.*, 1991JChemEduc91 (https://doi.org/10.1021/ed068p91) is one (late) testament to this how to create them, especially when portable Nd:YAG lasers became popular.

Comment: See a setup discussed on physics.se: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/155216/possibility-of-making-an-experiment-in-a-classroom-to-simulate-dna-diffraction

Comment: @Buttonwood: Yes I have done that lab and have some nice images of the X pattern from a helical spring.

Comment: Well, this is reminds to [photo 51](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photo_51) ...

Answer (score 2):

Although the YouTube videos you linked is nice, one can only wish if they added some explanations too and a complete picture of the set-up. After watching the experiment. All I feel with the sawtooth diffraction is that it is a very broad central maximum. It is not a sin *x* <-> *F*(sin*x*) pair. I don't think such a pair exists in diffraction, because if the were a pure sine FT, the central maximum must be absent. We should get just two spot corresponding to the sine wave frequency. Diffraction could be occuring at the very tips of the sawtooths. However, single slit diffraction (rectangular window) and the sinc function like appearance on a wall (Fourier transform of the rectangular window) is a decent illustration of optical transform pair.

In terms of X-rays, I recalled an demo experiment in an old book using four transmission gratings. You can easily buy transmission diffraction gratings from Edmund Optics. Fortunately, the book is available on Internet Archive. See Nokes, *Demonstrations in Modern Physics* (Second Edition). You can judge from the yellow pages that how old the book is but sometimes old books have treasures.

The author on page 103-105 shows four diffractions gratings in a concentric tube and each tube can be independently rotated or in other words, each diffraction grating can be crossed as follows:

[image: gratings]

When you pass collimated beam of visible light, through the four gratings set-up, a beautiful diffraction pattern is formed, very much like a Laue's diffraction pattern of X-rays and crystals.

[image]

Comment: This is neat. Not sure I see a direct connection to the question but a very interesting set-up.

Comment: The diffraction is similar to Laue pattern of X-ray diffraction which is also a Fourier transform of electron density in solids. Can you elaborate your question a little bit more? You have a saw there in the video, which you say, is close to a sine wave shape. Its FT is a displaced delta function.  Optically, how do you see a delta function on the screen?

Comment: Right, it's diffraction that gives Fourier images. My question concerns the particular Fourier transform pair. What I expect is that both the sine and the delta function will  be rough approximations of the mathematics. For the delta function, maybe two points of intensity to either side of the center. So in the video we see a saw blade and a *series* of vertical lines. I expect only two. Is this because there are other frequencies in the saw-sine?  I have no idea. Maybe Young's double slit gives a good approximation for certain slit dimensions. Does this help?

Comment: @daniel, I do not think that such an optical pair exists for sin x,->F(sin x). Maybe a single slit diffraction will be equivalent to a sinc function. This could be used to illustrate optical FT concept.

Comment: You may be right but then what do you think the saw-blade is showing at 1:11?

Comment: I really wish the YouTuber showed the optical path of the whole set up. All I feel is that it is a very broad central maximum. Diffraction could be occuring at the very tips of the sawtooths. However, single slit diffraction (rectangular window) and the sinc function like appearance on a wall (Fourier transform of the rectangular window) is a decent illustration of optical transform pair.

Comment: @daniel, I edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks--Could you include your assertion that the particular optical pair probably isn't feasible? I don't trust comments to hang around indefinitely..

Answer (score 2):

In *Optics* at p. 513$^*$ the authors state that Young's double-slit is the practical realization of the Fourier sine-delta pair, noting that the approximations to $\delta$ functions have finite shape which means the transform (sine wave) will not be ideal.

(Can skip)

The practical transform is created by convolving the $\delta$ slits with a rectangle. In the frequency domain this corresponds to multiplication of a sinc and sine function which gives a frequency-modulated sinc. That function is then squared to get the intensity and resembles the usual double slit pattern.

Also, as the distance between slits is decreased to nothing, the double-slit pattern merges continuously into the single-slit pattern shown below (my photo). So the answer to the OP is "yes" but it's not visually obvious.

[image]

$^*$Hecht and Ganesan, *Optics* (Pearson, 2015)